# Create Instance

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm new to Blender, I've been studying it for about 3 months,
currently I am 2 months working on this project: Fushima Castle,
only once I finished modeling the buildings, I realized I made a big mistake: I created thousands of objects without ever instantiating...
in particular, the edge of each single tile has a decoration and each roof has more sculptures (Yakugawara)

I wanted to ask for confirmation: once all these objects have been created, there is no going back? if I want a lighter project, would I have to re-do it all over again..?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select all tiles and *Link Object Data* under Ctrl+L, or *Object > Link/Transfer Data*.
This is the equivalent of doing *Linked Duplicates* (Alt+D) to begin with.
If you've individually modified them in edit mode, this could lose some information.

Comment: before asking this question, I searched the site about it, and I have already tried what you recommended! but thanks for your answer:
each single  roof tile has a decoration parallel to the next tile, so in this case, I think the best solution is to use a sequencer modifier... to avoid moving them individually by hand, the problem is that then I have to make proportional deformations to follow the slope of the roof .... I repeat .. I have been using blender for about 3 months, I started this project 2 months ago ... I'm a rookie .. XD

Comment: Now that you've already moved them by hand, there's nothing to be gained by switching to array (I assume that's what you mean by "sequencer"). There are other ways of instancing as well (on verts or faces), and you could, in theory, merge each mesh into a single vert, then join the objects into one and use it as an instancer. But the point of that is usually to save time, not add more work.

Comment: It's an ambitious project to start at one month.  It looks like it's progressed well.

Comment: yesterday I spent at least 12 hours of work just reviewing the project, the instance is a concept that I had to know right away: I knew the possibility of instantiating an object instead of duplicating it, but I've never done it because I didn't know that it allowed you to save resources on your pc...! Now that I get it, I'm trying to instantiate everything possible, the project has morphed from 5GB to 500MB!!!!!!! it's a fantastic thing: before, the more I added details, the heavier it became, the more I add instances the more the project gets lighter
a magic I didn't know..!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking in the *Outliner* you can right click the object's mesh data and then click *Remap Users*.

[image]

Select the desired mesh in the popup box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I created an instance and re-positioned every single decoration of every roof tile and every Yakugawara... (about 15 hours of work)
now the project has gone from 5 GB to 500 mb!!! :D I bring you a screenshot of the statistics to ask you if I exaggerated with the number of vertex faces...!
(I haven't instantiated the stone walls and the tiles out of exhaustion...) I've been working on this single project every day for more than two months, I would like to finally start working on texture colors and nodes